# Setting color of visited link with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink, click, visited

```
divText += '<div class="single-article"> ';
divText += '<h2><a href="#" onClick="javascript:displayArticleDetail('+json._embedded.articles[i].articleId+', \''+escapedLinkTitle+'\'); setVisited();" \>'+json._embedded.articles[i].title+'</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
```

I need some assistance setting the color of a visited link. Having some trouble with this. I cannot use pure CSS `:visited` because this goes and changes the link color of every single link, not just the visited (clicked).

How would I go about doing this with Javascript?

Comment: Give it a class and use `.class-name:visited`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to give more specificity to that anchor tag.

Try giving it an `id` field and use `a#id:visited` when styling it

You could also use `class` and select it with `a.class:visited`

Comment: this still applies the visited color to all links instead of just the one clicked

Comment: i need to onClick give only the clicked link some kind of visited attribute so only that one changes color (and the color stays even when going back and forth through pages)

Comment: I don't have anything in setVisited yet just left it in my html

Comment: Here is an example of using the id in a click handler http://jsfiddle.net/t5goh0e1/2/

Answer (score 0):

Ideally this should solve your problem,

```
a:visited {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

but even if you want to handle it with javascript:

you can use

```
document.getElementById("#elementID").style.color = "#ff0000";
```

or if you are using jQuery you can add a class to the element on click.